# Ag-grid Height inside flex-box row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ag-grid

I am having trouble configuring my ag-grid height correctly in Internet Explorer. It is working fine in both Chrome and Edge.

```
<div class="row search-result-row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-block h-100">

                <ag-grid-aurelia #agGrid class="ag-bootstrap"
                         style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                         grid-options.bind="gridOptions"
                         column-defs.bind="columnDefs">
                </ag-grid-aurelia>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer div with **class="row search-result-row"** contains a **flex-grow: 1** css class that expands the row height to fill the remaining screen space. There is then bootstrap card with a h-100 CSS class to set height of 100%.

The problem I have is with the ag-grid. In chrome and edge setting a height of 100% on the grid fills the div as expected however the behaviors in Internet explorer is very different. It seems to be on a continuous loop of expanding height on both the ag-grid and the top level row div causing two ever expanding scroll bars.

I can avoid this behavior if I explicitly set a height on the grid or one of the outer divs however this is not what I need. Is there a known issue or something I'm missing with regards to rendering an ag-grid with height:100% inside a flex-grow row and several other divs of `height : 100%`.

Please see this plunkr for an example of my problem in IE. I have explicitly added the css to show what the bootstrap classes are adding.
https://plnkr.co/edit/csEfhyrhQLjI196c1cER?p=preview

Comment: Using `height: 100%` with Flexbox is not gonna work properly, so if you provide a working code snippet, with linked `ag-grid` resources, you will get a proper answer.

Comment: Furthermore, the _card with a `h-100` class (setting height to 100%)_, how does its parent, the `col`, get its height, and how does the `col`'s parent, the `row`, get its height?

Comment: @LGSon apologies, I have this plunkr that domnstrates my problem in IE ... https://plnkr.co/edit/csEfhyrhQLjI196c1cER?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE need `flex: 1` instead of `flex-grow: 1`, which simply put mean, *take remaining space regardless of content size*

*I also added a fix for Firefox, and you can read more here if you want a great explanation:*

- *[Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size/36247448#36247448)*

```
.second-row{
  flex: 1;                     /*  changed, fix for IE  */
  min-height: 0;               /*  added, fix for Firefox  */
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Stack snippet

```js
// this example has items declared globally. bad javascript. but keeps the example simple.

var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Date", 
    field: "date",
    cellRenderer : function(params) {
      console.log('inside cell renderer, got ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(params.value));
      return params.value.toLocaleString();
    },
    filter: 'set',
    filterParams : {
      cellRenderer : function(params) {
        console.log('inside filter cell renderer, got ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(params.value));
        return params.value.toLocaleString();
      }
    }
    }
];

var rowData = [
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
        {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-09-02T12:15:02.904Z')},
    {date: new Date('2015-11-10T23:15:02.904Z')}
    
];

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    enableColResize: true,
    enableFilter: true
};


// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise
// ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // angularGrid is a global function
    agGridGlobalFunc('#myGrid', gridOptions);
    gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

html{
  height: 100%;;
  width: 100%;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@4.0.0-alpha.4" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/2.3.5/ag-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/2.3.5/ag-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/2.3.5/theme-fresh.css" />
    <style>
    
    #container{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .first-row{
      background-color: blue;
      /*flex-grow: 0;                  default, not needed  */
      display: flex;
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: -15px;
    }
    
    .second-row{
      flex: 1;                     /*  added, fix for IE  */
      min-height: 0;               /*  added, fix for Firefox  */
      display: flex;
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: -15px;
    }
    
    .col{
      flex-basis: 0;
      flex-grow:1;
      max-width: 100%;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .card{
      position: relative;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-width: 0;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      background-color: #fff;
      background-clip: border-box;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
    
    
    
    .h-100{
      height: 100%;
    }
  
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Put your html here! -->
    <div id="container">
      <div class="row first-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-block">
              This is the card
              This is the card
              This is the card
              This is the card
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         
      </div>
      <div class="row second-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-block h-100">
              <div id="myGrid" style="height:100%;" class="ag-fresh"></div> 
            </div>
             
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou, been bugging me for ages and to find its something so simple is almost annoying :)

Comment: @jjharrison I also added a fix for Firefox